# How to specify a layer for search in viewer.search() method?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I need to specify the layer in which it is necessary to find id, so that the search is not carried out on many layers of the model. can I add argument with layer name? Maybe like this [attributeName, layerName]?

```
viewer.search('"' + i['displayValue'] + '"', function(dbIds) {
    getSubset(dbIds, "MEASUREDLENGTH", i['displayValue'], function(propsObj) {
        obj.push({
            type: "LineString",
            properties: propsObj,
            geometry: {
                type: "LineString",
                coordinates: returnShortLine(extractPath(viewer, j)),
            }
        });
    })
}, function(error) {}, ["MEASUREDLENGTH", ???layer???]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible try pass in attribute names to look up to filter the results by layer -  `search(text, onSuccessCallback, onErrorCallback, attributeNames)`:

```
viewer.search(text, onSuccessCallback, onErrorCallback, ['attributeName', 'attributeName' ...])
```

Since search is directly performed against the property DB it's difficult to apply filters/conditions or customize its behavior by extending Viewer - I'd recommend to filter the results (read their properties to identify their layers etc.) to achieve the desired output.

Alternatively you can query against the property db directly - see [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/working-viewer-data-serverlessly-thumbnails-screesnshots-and-serverless-upload) and [here](https://github.com/yiskang/forge-propdb-reader-demo).

Comment: Thanks! I think additional requests do not optimize the speed of the program.